# Why isn't the size of my array 4 bytes in C

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

```
char foo[3] = { 97, 98, 97 };
printf("%d",sizeof(foo));
```

After debugging it gives me a result of  3.

**Why isn't the result 4?**

`foo[3]` consists of 4 characters 0,1,2,3 right?

Size of char is 1 byte so why isn't foo 4 bytes?

**Why isn't the result 1?**

When i call `foo` it is the same as calling `&foo[0]`.
So how do i know when i'm calling for whole array and when for the first character? like here `sizeof(foo)`

Comment: Three characters: `foo[0], foo[1], foo[2]`.  You asked for 3, you got 3.

Comment: Wrong. `foo` consists of 3 characters.

Comment: Where in the world did you get `0, 1, 2, 3` from in `foo[3]`?

Comment: You only get an "extra" character if you initialize a char array from a string literal (and only if you leave space for it, or not specify the array size at all).

Comment: What are you doing with it that requires you to know whether it is the array or the first character?  If it is an array, what were you going to do with it.  Would it be any different if it was the first character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll take this one question at a time...

**Why isn't the result of `sizeof(foo)` 4?**

It's because you've only set the size of the `foo` array to `3` in the first statement `char foo[3]`. There would be no reason to expect `4` as a result when you've explicitly defined the bound as 3 `chars` which is 3 bytes.

**Why isn't the result 1?**

You're correct in saying that *in some cases*, calling `foo` is the same as `&foo[0]`. The most relevant of these cases to your question is when being passed as a pointer into a function as a parameter. In the case of the `sizeof` function, when you pass in your `foo` array pointer, the function iterators throughout the memory block associated with that argued pointer and returns the total size, therefore *not* being `1`.

Comment: That's not the only main case. Arithmetic expressions come to mind as well. In fact, arrays decays to pointers more often than not. An to nitpick `sizeof` is not a function, it's an operator, and it does no iteration.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, you're right. I only mention the function parameter example because it was relevant to his question

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused with array size and array indexing.  If you declare an array `a` of size 3 with the line `char a[3];`, it holds three elements, and those elements are accessed as `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`. Those are the only elements that exist in the array.  `a[3]` would be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

> `foo[3]` consists of 4 characters 0,1,2,3 right?

No. The array of `char`, `foo` holds three elements: `foo[0], foo[1], foo[2]`. Since a char is always of size 1 (not necessarily a byte!) an array of three chars will therefore have a sizeof 3.

As for your second question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) SO question may shed some light on it.